# Multiple replacement by matching values within one row

Tags: r, dataframe, matching

Maybe a little bit silly question, but I can't manage to solve my problem.
I have a table with some codes, where some rows contains few codes separated by space:

```html
| Codes       |
|-------------|
| 12.12       |
| 12.12 12.13 |
| 12.11 12.13 |
| 12.10       |
```

I have to match this code with values from another table

```html
| Code  | Value |
|-------|-------|
| 12.10 | AA    |
| 12.11 | BB    |
| 12.12 | CC    |
| 12.13 | DD    |
```

to get the following result (desired separator is comma, but it doesn't really matter):

```html
| Codes |
|-------|
| CC    |
| CC,DD |
| BB,DD |
| AA    |
```

I have tried to achieve result like this:

`dataframe1$Codes <- dataframe2$values[match(unlist(strsplit(dataframe1 $Codes)) ,dataframe2$Code)]`

But I get error: replacement has X rows, data has Y

Comment: I believe the issue is that when you `unlist` you're changing the size of your vector, which means that `$values` and `$codes` no longer have the same length.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your data:

```
df <- data.frame(Codes=c("12.12","12.12 12.13","12.11 12.13","12.10"),
                 stringsAsFactors=F)
vals <- data.frame(Code=c("12.10","12.11","12.12","12.13"),
                   Value=c("AA","BB","CC","DD"),
                   stringsAsFactors=F)
```

I use `dplyr` and `iterators`:

```
library(dplyr)
library(iterators)
```

Make a nested list of `Codes` in `df`:

```
temp <- lapply(iter(df,by="row"),function(x) unlist(strsplit(x," ")))
```

Match `df$Codes` to `vals$Code`, grab paired `vals$Value`, and `paste` and convert to data frame:

```
df1 <- lapply(iter(temp),function(x) paste0(vals$Value[vals$Code %in% x],collapse=",")) %>% 
     do.call(rbind,.) %>%
     as.data.frame() %>%
     rename(Codes=V1)
```

Output

```
  Codes
1    CC
2 CC,DD
3 BB,DD
4    AA
```